# Issue copying cell value to clipboard (DataObject) on DoubleClick in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA. I am having issues trying to automatically copy the text from a cell which has been double-clicked. I have tried every which way, but something is obviously wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code in ThisWorkbook:

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyData As DataObject

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = False
    Set MyData = New DataObject
    MyData.SetText Target.Text
    MyData.PutInClipboard
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it should work fine (assuming you have a reference to the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library). But when I tried it all I got was a couple of square characters. If I removed the `Cancel = True` line, then it worked fine, but probably not what you want.

No idea why it isn't working with the `Cancel = True`, but with a bit of playing around this seemed to work:

```
Option Explicit

Dim MyData As DataObject

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = False
    Set MyData = New DataObject
    Target.Copy
    MyData.GetFromClipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MyData.PutInClipboard
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Noting also that this should be in the sheet code module and not the `ThisWorkbook` module.

Comment: Okay, so I moved this to the Sheet code and still no joy. I have the Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library reference in place. This is now returning a Run-time Error indicating "DataObject:PutInClipboard could not complete the operation dur to error 80004001"